# How to print the output of `read -p` to stdout and another file

Tags: bash, pipe, read, tee

I was doing

```
echo -n "  - This directory is not empty, purge? (Y/N):   " | tee -a $mylogs
read choice
echo "$choice" | tee -a $mylogs
```

but I wanted to try to condense it to:

```
read -p "  - This directory is not empty, purge? (Y/N): " choice | tee -a $mylogs
```

This prints to stdout but not to `$mylogs`. Also, nothing is saved in `$choice`. Is there an explanation as to why this is? Any 1 or 2 line alternatives that

- print the prompt
- print user input
- save the input in `$choice`

I would like to log only this part of the script and be able to reuse `$choice`

Comment: `read` does not print anything to stdout. You will need to do that yourself with something like the echo statement above.

Comment: Do you want the prompt string to appear in the log, or just the user input? if the former, then remember that the prompt is printed via stderr not stdout

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to get both, but thanks for pointing out the `stderr` point about `read -p`. Still working on getting the user input printed and the user input saved to $choice.

Comment: I don't know how to flag a duplicate question, but this is possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233811/duplicate-stdin-to-stdout "Duplicate stdin to stdout"

Comment: ** it should be something like this but I'm getting nothing in `$mylogs` ... `read -p "  - This directory is not empty, purge? (Y/N): " choice | tee >(echo "$(</dev/stdin)") |tee -a $mylogs`

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of reading around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985060/bash-script-using-script-command-from-a-bash-script-for-logging-a-session) courtesy of @lesmana which may help

Run your script with

```
script -q -a -f logfile -c 'sh ./yourscriptname'
```

To hide this logging from the 'user' I just put this one line script as a wrapper for the target script and then invoked the target script from the wrapper.

Comment: Thank for your time, but weird things happened for me. I think it's because my `script` doesn't support `-c`. So it would only print the prompt after I typed exit.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: My bad, my shell does support the -c option. I had mistakenly put `sript` inside my "yourscriptname" and then called it with `script` again, so it was like script inception and was causing weird behavior. Cool stuff, but this code is just a small part, and I'd like to use the `$choice`  further down, and using this script call doesn't allow me to use the variable that is read.

Comment: Strange. My main script `echo`ed $choice after the `read -p` perfectly fine. I did check before posting

Comment: yes $choice is `echo`able in "yourscriptname", but everything in yourscriptname will be logged. I need to use $choice after yourscriptname is finished with other code that won't be logged. So it'd be like


``code...`` then in the same file
``script -q -a -f logfile -c 'sh ./yourscriptname' #this stuff is logged in logfile`` THEN
``if [[ $choice = "Y" ]]; then ...#stuff that shouldn't be logged`` at this point $choice is undefined for you, too, right?

Comment: I had rather thought that you wanted your entire script logged and would therefore invoke your entire script through the wrapper, Seems you are after a 'one-shot' affair I will think on some more....If I come up with anything then I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I realized that `tee` can read from the original `stdin` if nothing is piped to it, so I thought I'd add another solution in case it helps anyone who stumbles upon this later.

Thanks to @steeldriver for pointing out that `read -p` prints to `stderr` not `stdout`. So closest I've got is:

```
read -p "  - This directory is not empty, purge? (Y/N): " choice 2> >(tee -a $mylogs)
echo $choice >> $mylogs
```

Source and explanation for what's going on can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/11024335). For this specific example, the first line is able to redirect `stderr` to `tee` to print the prompt in `$mylogs` and to `stdout`.

However, `read` seems to be doing something to make it impossible to intercept the user input and send it to `$mylogs` and not just `$choice`.

The other solution is simpler and shorter, but less user friendly and readable (unless many people know that `read` isn't the only command to read input so simply):

```
echo -n "  - This directory is not empty, purge? (Y/N): " | tee -a $mylogs
choice=$(tee -a $mylogs)
```

So in the second line `tee` provides a way to give the user input to **both** `$mylogs` **and** `$choice`, unlike `read`, but obviously there's no *prompt* option (`-p`). So still 2 lines.

Also, you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to submit. This might be bad for my Y/N situation, but might be nice for multi-line answers since you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to stop.